# Using jquery to hide or show multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a common problem, but with a unique twist.  I have a list of checkboxes.  For each checkbox, I want to hide/show one or more divs.  Something like this-  If I check checkbox 1, div 1 shows.  If I check checkbox 2, div 2 shows.  If I check checkbox 3, divs 1 AND 2 show.  Here is the twist, if I select checkboxes 1 and 3, then uncheck 3, I want div 1 to stay visible.  The code would be something like this (with only the 1 and 2 checkboxes working)-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="1">1
<input type="checkbox" name="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="2">2
<input type="checkbox" name="???">1&2

<div id="showme1" style="display: none">Show me1</div>
<div id="showme2" style="display: none">Show me2</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var MyCheckboxes1=$("input[name='1']");

MyCheckboxes1.change(function() {
  $("#showme1").toggle(MyCheckboxes1.is(":checked"));
});

var MyCheckboxes2=$("input[name='2']");

MyCheckboxes2.change(function() {
  $("#showme2").toggle(MyCheckboxes2.is(":checked"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: As an update I tried using class to do this by assigning two classes to the 1&2 box like this-  <input type="checkbox" class="1" class="2">  but still no luck.  IT only recognized the first.  I am starting to wonder if this will have to be more complicated than I had planned :(

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this, simple logic, using if else statements based on if a checkbox is checked or not: http://jsfiddle.net/qvhpfzs7/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1"/> show Div 1
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c2"/> show Div 2
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="c3"/> show Div 1 AND Div 2
<br/><br/>
<div class="div1">THIS IS THE CONTENT OF DIV 1</div>
<div class="div2">THIS IS THE CONTENT OF DIV 2</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div1').hide();
    $('.div2').hide();
    var d1 = false;
    var d2 = false;
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
        if ($('#c1').is(':checked')) { d1 = true; }
        else { d1 = false; }
        if ($('#c2').is(':checked')) { d2 = true; }
        else { d2 = false; }
        if ($('#c3').is(':checked')) {
            d1 = true;
            d2 = true;
        }
        if (d1) { $('.div1').show(); } else { $('.div1').hide(); }
        if (d2) { $('.div2').show(); } else { $('.div2').hide(); }  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some playing, and an idea from a friend and brainiac named Brian, here is what I came up with for a solution.  Pretty simple once I thought about it.

HTML-

```
<div id="showme1" style="display: none">Show me1</div>
<div id="showme2" style="display: none">Show me2</div>
```

JS-

```
var MyCheckboxes1=$("input[class='1']");

MyCheckboxes1.change(function() {
  $("#showme1").toggle(MyCheckboxes1.is(":checked") || MyCheckboxes12.is(":checked"));
});

var MyCheckboxes2=$("input[class='2']");

MyCheckboxes2.change(function() {
  $("#showme2").toggle(MyCheckboxes2.is(":checked") || MyCheckboxes12.is(":checked"));
});


var MyCheckboxes12=$("input[class='12']");

MyCheckboxes12.change(function() {
  $("#showme1").toggle(MyCheckboxes1.is(":checked") || MyCheckboxes12.is(":checked"));
  $("#showme2").toggle(MyCheckboxes2.is(":checked") || MyCheckboxes12.is(":checked"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Alright this is what I have. Check the code below**

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="1">1
  <input type="checkbox" name="1">1
  <input type="checkbox" name="2">2
  <input type="checkbox" name="2">2
  <!-- <input type="checkbox" name="???">1&2 -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="3">3

  <div id="showme1" style="display: none">Show me1</div>
  <div id="showme2" style="display: none">Show me2</div>

<script>
  var MyCheckboxes1=$("input[name='1']");

  MyCheckboxes1.change(function() {
    $("#showme1").toggle(MyCheckboxes1.is(":checked"));
  });

  var MyCheckboxes2=$("input[name='2']");

  MyCheckboxes2.change(function() {
    $("#showme2").toggle(MyCheckboxes2.is(":checked"));
  });

  var MyCheckboxes3=$("input[name='3']");

  MyCheckboxes3.change(function() {
       <!-- for checkbox 3 I just toggled showme 1 & 2 -->
      $("#showme1").toggle();
      $("#showme2").toggle();
  });    
</script>
```

**If 1 and 3 is selected, then uncheck 3 then 1 is still visible.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've tried. Hope this helps.

JavaScript -

```
function handleClick(cb) {
        if(cb.checked==true){
            if(cb.name==3){ // Show both div
                $('#showme1').show();
                $('#showme2').show();
            }else{
                $('#showme'+cb.name).show();
            }
        }else{
            if(cb.name==3){ // Show both div 
                $('#showme1').hide();
                $('#showme2').hide();
            }else{
                $('#showme'+cb.name).hide();
            }
        }
      }
```

HTML -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="1" onclick='handleClick(this);'>1
<input type="checkbox" name="1" onclick='handleClick(this);'>1
<input type="checkbox" name="2" onclick='handleClick(this);'>2
<input type="checkbox" name="2" onclick='handleClick(this);'>2
<input type="checkbox" name="3" onclick='handleClick(this);'>3

<div id="showme1" style="display: none">Show me1</div>
<div id="showme2" style="display: none">Show me2</div>
```

You can also use toggle() when div(s) are initially shown.